# Install files to original user's My Docs folder via Inno Setup on Windows Vista/7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, uac, inno-setup

In the `[Run]` section of an Inno Setup script, there's a flag `runasoriginaluser` that allows the script to run a process as the original user:

> the spawned process will execute with
>   the (normally non-elevated)
>   credentials of the user that started
>   Setup initially (i.e., the "pre-UAC
>   dialog" credentials).

**Is there an equivalent flag or workaround for the `{userdocs}` shell folder constant?**

This is apparently a known limitation within Inno Setup (and other installers, generally), but I'm hoping someone knows a workaround.

Excerpt from the Inno Setup help file:

> The "user" constants refer to the
>   profile of the user running Setup.
>   This user is often not the same as the
>   currently logged-in user, so use the
>   "user" constants with caution.

Comment: What files are you wanting to install in the 'My Documents' folder? I ask because this isn't a location commonly used to install files in.

Comment: In many ways, this is a non-traditional install.  It is a tax collection system, used by 50 or so users.  Several times a year we send out program updates (which do not require writing anything to the My Documents folder).  However, twice a year we need to send out updated data files.  Occasionally we get a new tax collector who needs a complete program install (as opposed to an update).  In the past, we had three different processes to handle these scenarios (a data file update, a program update, and a program install).  We are trying to get to a single Inno Setup "install" to do all three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I came up with was using an external script to perform the data copy and calling the script using the `ExecAsOriginalUser` function in the `wpReady` page of the `NextButtonClick` event function.

I'll provide more details if anyone is interested.

Comment: This approach does not work. I've posted why in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526350/how-to-write-to-the-users-my-documents-directory-with-installer-not-easy-if-us

Comment: The approch does work for that one user when the setup is run normally. When the user explicitly does "Run as admin" then it changes the game. It's still better practice to [move this into the application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10532282/588306) though.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not correct.

There two correct ways:

1. If the installer installs the application for the current (unprivileged) user only, do not require Administrator privileges, by setting [`PrivilegesRequired`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) to `lowest`:

   ```
   [Setup]
   PrivilegesRequired=lowest
   ```

   Then the "user" constants will correctly refer to the current user's folder.
2. If the installer installs the application for all users, it does not make sense to put some files to folder of one specific users. All users need the files, not just the one. In this case the recommended approach is to install the files to "Common" folder, using the [`{commonappdata}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=commonappdata) (or similar). And have the application copy the files to the user folder on the first run.

   See also [How to write to the user's My Documents directory with installer when the user used 'Run As Administrator'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10526350/850848).

You can also allow the user choose between these two approaches.
See [Make Inno Setup installer request privileges elevation only when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21556853/850848).

For another similar questions, see

- [Inno Setup Using {localappdata} for logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40613608/850848)
- [Inno Setup always installs into admin's AppData directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29376898/850848#43248500)

---

Having that said, you can, as you have found yourself, by execute an external copy utility ([`copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy), [`xcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy), [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)) using the [`ExecAsOriginalUser` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_execasoriginaluser) (or the [`runasoriginaluser` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=runasoriginaluser) in the `[Run]` section).

```pascal
ExecAsOriginalUser(
  'cmd.exe', '/c xcopy.exe "sourcefile" "%APPDATA%"',
  '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

For more detail on this approach, see a similar question [Inno Setup Creating registry key for logged in user (not admin user)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28824766/850848).

Though, if the installer was started elevated straight away (as opposite to elevating itself), the above won't work. And it cannot work in this scenario anyway. See [How to write to the user's My Documents directory with installer when the user used 'Run As Administrator'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10526350/850848). For this reason, stick with the approaches described above.