# Creating registry key for logged in user (not admin user) in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, registry, inno-setup, regedit

I'm trying to create an installer using Inno setup when I encounter this problem, everything else is being installed, but the registry keys are not being installed in the current user, I can't find it in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. But when I try to run the `regedit` as Administrator, the registry is installed there. I have UAC turned on and validating with an admin account for the install to run, why is that happening?

Here's my `Registry` section

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey:Software; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueName:ABS; ValueType:string; ValueData:ABS;
Root: HKCU; Subkey:Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\ABS.ScriptManager; Flags: uninsdeletekey;
Root: HKCU; Subkey:Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\ABS.ScriptManager; ValueName:Description; ValueType:string; ValueData:Script Manager; Flags: uninsdeletekey;
```

Note: I'm running 32 bit Windows 7

Answer (score 4):

I do not think you can write explicitly to registry keys of logged in user from Inno Setup. You can write to registry keys of the user which is running the installer only.

You can write to any (or all) user's registry keys via `HKEY_USERS`, but I do not know, if you can tell, which user is logged in.

---

But you can execute an external application that writes the registry key as part of the installation using the [`runasoriginaluser`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) flag or the [`ExecAsOriginalUser`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_execasoriginaluser) function.

You can use the [`reg.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) for this:

```
[Run]
Filename: reg.exe; \
    Parameters: "ADD HKCU\Software\MyProgram /v Foo /t REG_SZ /d Bar"; \
    Flags: runasoriginaluser runhidden
```

or

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Params: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Log('Adding registry key for original user');
    Params := 'ADD HKCU\Software\xxxx /v Foo /t REG_SZ /d Bar';
    if ExecAsOriginalUser(
         'reg.exe', Params, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) and
       (ResultCode = 0) then
    begin
      Log('Added registry key for original user');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Error adding registry key for original user');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

*Credits for the idea: [@Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28824766/850848#40300297). Though note that this won't work if the user explicitly runs your installer as Administrator, as then the "original" user will be the Administrator already. For a general discussion of the problem, see [Installing application for currently logged in user from Inno Setup installer running as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44575666/850848)*.

Answer (score 2):

in [Run] section with:
Filename: reg.exe; Parameters: "IMPORT ..." and flag: runascurrentuser!

Comment: A bit more prose might be helpful ;)

Comment: I guess you meant the flag runasoriginaluser instead of runascurrentuser, see [Inno Setup Help](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection)

Answer (score 1):

From the wording of your question, it sounds like this is because you are "validating with an admin account for the install to run." If this is the case and you are entering a different account (from that which you are logged in with) at the UAC prompt, the current user then actually becomes the Administrator account you just entered at the UAC prompt and not the account you are logged in with. What you may need to do is use the `runasoriginaluser` function, which will use the logged in user credentials instead of the account you entered at the UAC prompt.

Comment: in what part do I need to include that?